# Suppress the source and event type in TraceSource.TraceEvent

Tags: c#, .net

This statement, TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "Hello Trace"), will produce a trace log that looks like below:

```
com.spok.TestDB Information: 1 : Hello Trace.
```

Is there a way to config the Trace to suppress the "com.spok.TestDB Information" text, which is the source name + TraceEventType, from the log?
Another word, I want it to produce only this:

```
Hello Trace.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5141xyx5(v=vs.110).aspx), the output depends on the listener, and if you want to change it then you'll have to create your own listener that overrides the right methods.

> The trace content is listener specific. If the method is not overridden by the listener implementation, the default output is the name of the trace source, its numeric identity, the event type, and the message. Additional trace content is dependent upon the listener's TraceOutputOptions property value.

Here's a small example. It creates a new listener that derives from an existing one, and overrides the `TraceEvent()` behavior to output just the *"Hello Trace"* message. It's a silly example, but it should get you started.

```
class Program
{
    // Define your own TraceSource and Listener
    private static TraceSource mySource =
        new TraceSource("MyTraceSourceApp", SourceLevels.Information);
    private static TraceListener myListener =
        new MyTraceListener { TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.None };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Associate the Listener with the TraceSource
        mySource.Listeners.Add(myListener);

        mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "Hello Trace");

        Console.ReadLine();  // pause so we can see the output
    }
}

class MyTraceListener : ConsoleTraceListener
{
    public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string message)
    {
        // Do whatever you want in here - you're in control of the implementation
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]